# Why does the tutorial part three does not work?

Tags: gatsby

Help please, I could not understand whats happening while doing tutorial-part-three:

kemal@kemal-LENOVO3000-V200:~/tutorial-part-three$ ls
gatsby-config.js  LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  http://README.md  src  static  utils  yarn.lock
kemal@kemal-LENOVO3000-V200:~/tutorial-part-three$ gatsby develop

ERROR

The above error occurred in the  component:
    in ReduxStoreProvider
    in App

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, App.

ERROR

Warning: App: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI.

ERROR

UNHANDLED REJECTION Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Error: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen   for one of the following reasons:
  1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
  2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
  3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

- react.development.js:1607 
  [tutorial-part-three]/[gatsby]/[react]/cjs/react.development.js:1607:26
- react.development.js:1610 resolveDispatcher
  [tutorial-part-three]/[gatsby]/[react]/cjs/react.development.js:1610:5
- react.development.js:1636 useState
  [tutorial-part-three]/[gatsby]/[react]/cjs/react.development.js:1636:20
- index.js:28 ReduxStoreProvider
  [tutorial-part-three]/[gatsby]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/reporter/loggers/ink/index.js:28:41
- react-reconciler.development.js:5671 renderWithHooks
  [tutorial-part-three]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:5671:18
- react-reconciler.development.js:7905 mountIndeterminateComponent
  [tutorial-part-three]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:7905:13
- react-reconciler.development.js:9049 beginWork$1
  [tutorial-part-three]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:9049:16
- react-reconciler.development.js:10317 Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
  [tutorial-part-three]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:10317:10
- react-reconciler.development.js:10501 invokeGuardedCallback
  [tutorial-part-three]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:10501:31
- react-reconciler.development.js:14014 beginWork$$1
  [tutorial-part-three]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:14014:7

kemal@kemal-LENOVO3000-V200:~/tutorial-part-three$

Comment: Hi there! What tutorial, from where? Please fix your title, it doesnt make sense

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error on [tutorial three - Creating Nested Layout Components](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-three/) on the Gatsby Website. I was able to fix it by using yarn instead of npm on this cmd -

Instead of this:

```
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-typography react-typography typography typography-theme-fairy-gates
```

Try this:

```
yarn add gatsby-plugin-typography react-typography typography typography-theme-fairy-gates
```